# Using update from the same table with ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update a field from my table using another field from the same table, but when I run the update below I get an error

```
update f1
set f1.usu_cgcstr = f2.cgccpf
from E095for as f1
join E095for as f2
on f1.codfor = f2.codfor
where  f1.usu_intot = 'N'
```

Error:

> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

So how I can do this update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax; use `merge`:

```
merge into f1
  using e095for f2
  on (f1.codfor = f2.codfor)
  when matched then update set f1.usu_cgcstr = f2.cgccpf
  where f1.usu_intot = 'N';
```

---

Or, if you wanted `update`:

```
update e095for f1 set
  f1.usu_intot = (select f2.cgccpf
                  from e095for f2
                  where f2.codfor = f1.codfor
                 )
  where f1.usu_intot = 'N'
    and exists (select null from e095for c
                where c.codfor = f1.codfor
               );
```

Comment: Thanks, using merge Statement solve my problem.